# Cast Exception in recycler View?

Tags: android

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
```

> Here are my imports :

```
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

> Here is myOnCreateOptionsMenu () :

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

> XML :

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```

> Since everything has now migrated to AndroidX, how can I fix this Error, please reply with your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Check your ID in XML  which you used for search view

Comment: Update your declaration

Comment: ID is correct , also added the xml code @ArchuMohan

Comment: add your declaration part of the code.. then only we can find what actually happening

Comment: Add this    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" instead of androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView in your XML

Comment: IT WORKED, tnx Buddy @NovoLucas

Answer (score 0):

In your XML you can see that 
`app:actionViewClass=` is set to `"androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView"`.

Should be `"androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"`